# Unable to click on this Button using selenium (java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i have issues with `click();` function using **selenium webdriver**.

here's the outputHtml :

```
 <button type="button" class="k-button k-primary" tabindex="0" style="width: 50%;">Valider< /button>
```

i used the `findEelement` using various `xpath` like :

```
- "//button[@class = 'k-button k-primary' and @type = 'button']"
- "//*[contains(@class, 'k-button k-primary') and text()='Valider']"
```

and still got the error Unable to locate the element

here's the screenshot of the pop-up's Button that i need to click on (button Valider)

[Button : Valider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc67x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually copying and pasting the selector?

If you are on a Windows machine:

In Google Chrome if you press F12 to open the developer window.

Find the node you are looking for within the DOM and right click on it.

Then go to "Copy" and "Copy XPath" or you can "Copy JS Path"

Then you can paste the path into your code and try it that way.

I prefer to select dom nodes using the JS Path when I am developing with selenium.

The "Copy Full XPath" option is useful during development if you are having problems like you are because it copies the full path all the from the root node.

This feature is available in all major browsers but I am most familiar with developing with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Element has loaded when you are searching for it?  Try a break point before and verify it is available.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle alerts/pop-ups you need to switch to it

```
//switch to alert
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
//accept it
alert.accept();
// or accept it by your code
driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//button[@class = 'k-button k-primary' and @type = 'button']").click();
//dismiss alert
alert.dismiss();
//or dismiss with you code
driver.findElement(YOUR_LOCATOR).click();
//get text
String alertText = alert.getText()
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not really an alert and this is my issue,i cannot accept it by my code,i used the same code that you provided and i got the error unable to locate the element

Comment: can please share a screenshot with the page source?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the pop up is within some frame. If it is then you have to switch to the frame like this
driver.switchTo.frame(iframe locator)